# MonoLogger 9 Levels deep aborting normalization

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, monolog

I am trying to log a request that we are sending via guzzle which is deeply nested (upto 10-11 levels deep to be precise).

Logging the request with Monolog spits out:

> Over 9 levels deep, aborting normalization

on the deeply nested attributes.

The code is dead simple

```
// $requestData being the data I am sending via guzzle.
Log::info("Ekart Booking API:", $requestData);
```

Is there a way I can increase the Monolog's normalization depth?

Answer (score 6):

You can `json_encode` it:

```
Log::info("Ekart Booking API:" . json_encode($requestData));
```

Comment: Well, that is actually a quick and easiest solution :think_face:.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can play with this, it will change `NormalizerFormatter::$maxNormalizeDepth` on every formatters it found (that's maybe not what you want)

```
if ($logger instanceof \Monolog\Logger) {
    foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
        if ($handler instanceof \Monolog\Handler\FormattableHandlerInterface) {
            $formatter = $handler->getFormatter();
            if ($formatter instanceof \Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter) {
                $formatter->setMaxNormalizeDepth(50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of the `aborting normalization` errors in my log files, so I created this trait that I can plug in wherever it's needed.  We have code that uses both older and newer versions of Monolog, so it's designed to work with either.

```
use Psr\Log\LogInterface;

trait LogCustomize
{
    static public function setMaxLoggerNormalizeDepth(LoggerInterface $logger, int $depth): void
    {
        $handlers = $logger->getHandlers();
        foreach ($handlers as $handler) {
            $formatter = $handler->getFormatter();

            if (method_exists($formatter, 'setMaxNormalizeDepth')) {
                $formatter->setMaxNormalizeDepth($depth);
            } elseif (method_exists($formatter, 'setMaxDepth')) {
                // older versions of Monolog
                $formatter->setMaxDepth($depth);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just use it on a `$logger` instance like this:

```
$maxDepth = 20;
self::setMaxLoggerNormalizeDepth($logger, $maxDepth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Laravel, here is how can resolve this issue in Laravel by configuring the logging formatter.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels

Change your configuration to something like this:

```php
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class],
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

Then create a CustomzeFormatter class with the following content, based off of Axi's answer.

```php
<?php
 
namespace App\Logging;
 
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
 
class CustomizeFormatter
{
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof \Monolog\Handler\FormattableHandlerInterface) {
                $formatter = $handler->getFormatter();
                if ($formatter instanceof \Monolog\Formatter\NormalizerFormatter) {
                    $formatter->setMaxNormalizeDepth(50);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```